# A word for mutually and simultaneously influential

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a paper on how the imperial Russian state used its discursive power to shape and define the deviant nature of hooligan behavior. However, likewise, hooligans used published discourse—media, newspapers—to also shape perceptions of hooliganism even while being subjected to the state's discursive control. I am looking for a word that describes the mutual and simultaneous influence of the state and hooligans—despite their opposition—on public discourse. 
Thank you.

Comment: A vicious circle? Positive feedback?

Comment: Thank you Colin Fine. I think I'm looking for a more neutral, scientific term. Both of your suggestions seem to imply either a negative or positive connotation.

Comment: Maybe just [feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback), or feedback _loop_.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about why you're using the word "mutual," rather than "competitive?"

Comment: Would a word borrowed from the Mandarin [(guanxi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanxi) fit your desired meaning and usage?

Comment: file under "everyone needs a good enemy".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a good situation for "dialectical" - "concerned with or acting through opposing forces." I'd describe the kind of mutual influence you're writing about as a "dialectical dynamic."